# Analytic function on the complex plane except the negative real axis

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, analytic-functions, singularity

Let $G$ and $H$ be defined by

$G=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{z=x+iy: x\le 0, y=0\}$

$H=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{z=x+iy: x\in \mathbb{Z},x\le 0, y=0\}$

Suppose $f:G\to \mathbb{C} $ and $g:H \to \mathbb{C}$ are analytic functions.Consider the following statements.

I: $\int_{\gamma}f$ is independent of the path $\gamma$ in $G$ joining $-i$ and $i$.

II: $\int_{\gamma}g$ is independent of the path $\gamma$ in $H$ joining $-i$ and $i$.

Then which of the above statements is/are true?

My thoughts:-

For statement I

Let $\gamma_o$ be a fixed path in $G$ joining $i$ to $-i$.

Now if $\gamma$ be any path in $G$ joining $-i$ to $i$ then , let $\Gamma=\gamma+ \gamma_o$ , Then

$\int_{\Gamma}f=0$ (since there are no singularities within $\Gamma$)

$\Rightarrow \int_{\gamma}f+ \int_{\gamma_o}f=0$

$\Rightarrow \int_{\gamma}f=-\int_{\gamma_o}f$, for every $\gamma$ in $G$. So I is true

For statement II

I think it is false because there are paths which contain singularities but I cant write a formal proof.

Please help.Thanks for your time

Comment: Your understanding of Cauchy's Theorem is not correct. In $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ the function $\frac 1 z$ has no singularities but the integral of this function over the unit circle is not $0$. It is $2 \pi i$.

Comment: But sir , doesn't my choice of $\Gamma$ ensure that there are no singularities within it, and thus by Cauchy Goursat Theorem ,the integral is zero.

Comment: If $\int_{\gamma}=-\int_{\gamma_0}$ for any $\gamma$ then  $\int_{\gamma_0}=-\int_{\gamma_0}$ in particular. So  $\int_{\gamma}=0$. Do you think this is true?

Comment: Oh ! not at all. Does that mean I is  false.  What about II ? I am more confused now. How to proceed exactly?

Comment: I is true. I suppose that "no singularities within $\Gamma$" means that $\Gamma$ doesn't surround any singularity, not only that no singularity lies on (the trace of) $\Gamma$. What is missing in your argument is the _reason_ why there are no singularities within $\Gamma$.